# How do I separate a data frame into multiple data, filtering by row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I apologize for the vagueness of the question, but I am still new to R so I have not yet been antiquated to all of the proper terminology. Essentially, I have the following data:

```
Mydata <- data.frame(attr = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
type = c(1,3,1,1,1,5,1,1,8,1))
```

Say I want to create multiple different data frames, each one separated by when `type` does not equal one. My desired output is below:

```
   attr type
1    1    1

   attr type
1    2    3
2    3    1
3    4    1
4    5    1

   attr type
1    6    5
2    7    1
3    8    1

   attr type
1    9    8
2   10    1
```

How would I program this?

Comment: Side note: this is probably not a good idea. Instead, you can make a grouping column `Mydata$g <- cumsum(Mydata$type != 1)` (same as in Calum's answer) and do grouped operations (instead of iterating over a set of tables).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split` combined with `cumsum` to get a list of the desired data frames. This basically checks to see if a row isn't 1, generates group indices, and then uses `split` to get the right output. Consider using `dplyr::group_by` rather than `split` though if a list of data frames is not actually what you want, but rather just grouped calculations.

```r
Mydata <- data.frame(
  attr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  type = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 8, 1)
)
split(Mydata, cumsum(Mydata$type != 1))
#> $`0`
#>   attr type
#> 1    1    1
#> 
#> $`1`
#>   attr type
#> 2    2    3
#> 3    3    1
#> 4    4    1
#> 5    5    1
#> 
#> $`2`
#>   attr type
#> 6    6    5
#> 7    7    1
#> 8    8    1
#> 
#> $`3`
#>    attr type
#> 9     9    8
#> 10   10    1
```

Created on 2018-07-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! How do I call on an individual data frame?

Comment: `split` outputs a list, which can be indexed with `[[` or `$` . Lists are R's generic 1D structure for holding arbitrary objects; here we have a list where each element is a data frame. [Here's a detailed guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) to data structures in R, and [here's one for subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).